# Start a song from a specific time in rhythmbox using command line

Tags: bash, terminal, rhythmbox

I would like to start a song from my terminal, starting from the first minute.
i.e.: the command will run the *music.mp3* starting from the minute 1.

I am able to run a music with

```
 rhythmbox music.mp3
```

However it is starting from 0. How to do it for starting from minute 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the command line tool [rhythmbox-client](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/rhythmbox-client/). Looking at the options there's a `--seek` switch which should do what you want.

```
rhytmbox-client --seek=+60
```

There are [reports that this should work but doesn't](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1999956.html). Might be a bug?

As an alternative method you can fire the commands directly yourself using dbus:

```
# seek forward 60 sec
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.rhythmbox /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Seek int64:60000000
sleep 2    

# skip to next track
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.rhythmbox /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next
sleep 2

# toggle play/pause state
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.rhythmbox /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
sleep 2
```

A bit too verbose for routine command line use, so just pop them into conveniently named scripts, and away you go! The [list of commands can be found here](http://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/Player_Interface.html).

Comment: it's not working for me unfortunately. Is your code working on your system? Could you give me a sample working? Thanks in advance. (note that the link is not found)

Comment: Updated the link.

Comment: Ok I got it, I simply had to add a sleep between the 2 commands. Thanks for your help. Regards,